# "You are using an incompatible web browser" error when trying to access Facebook

Tags: windows, windows-xp, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am using Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Mozilla Firefox. None of them can access Facebook. I keep getting this error from all browsers that I use:

> You are using an incompatible web browse

How do I correct it?

I have searched the open questions, but have not found a specific answer to my question, or a simple answer to my question.

Comment: What browsers are you using? What sites are you going to?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without the info @Jin has requested, so I'll second that.  Please edit your question to contain this information.

Comment: I am using Chrome, Explorer, and Mozilla. None of them can access Facebook.

Comment: I am able to access every other site on the web, just not Facebook.

Comment: If it's only one site, this message is being generated by the website.  It's not really appropriate for Super User IMO then - maybe Webapps could help?

Comment: You should [edit] it. I did it for you, but please do this in the future if you have any relevant updates.

Comment: What does this website return? http://whatsmyuseragent.com/

Comment: Have you tried accessing it with all firewalls and internet security programs disabled?

Comment: What specific versions of the browsers are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with this one for a long time, tried dozens of things that were suggested by others, and finally cracked it this morning! I have Symantec Endpoint Protection installed. I had to go to Network Threat Protection -> Options -> Change Settings and under Stealth Settings, remove checks from all 3 boxes.

What's important is that this seems to be a case of your firewall, whatever kind you are running, trying to protect you from some transaction that is required by Facebook, so if you have a different firewall than Symantec Endpoint, look for some setting that might be filtering out what Facebook needs.

It is unfortunate that Facebook gives this very misleading error message under these conditions!  Symantec, at least, does warn you in the Settings box that enabling these settings may interfere with using some websites.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's affecting all 3 browsers, it's not likely a browser problem.  One issue that can cause this is security software blocking web sites from being able to detect your browser or operating system.

In Symantec and Norton security software, you need to disable "stealth" mode.  Here's a link which explains "Stealth Mode" and why it will cause this behavior:

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH103309

Which security software are you using?  Others may have a similar setting.  Try changing whatever setting allows web sites to detect your operating system and browser version.

Also try disabling any web filtering software, if you have any installed.

Answer (score 0):

Set a user agent:

```
httpRequest.UserAgent =
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)"
```